# How to build a list of filterable options from a query result?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have a collection of products, each product will have:

1. price
2. attributes (for example: Size: xl, s, xxl; Color: yellow, red, blue; ....)
3. manufacturer
4. categories (a product can be in multiple categories)

This collection is indexed in ElasticSearch. Now when I query the list of all products in category A for example, I would also like to get:

1. the price range of all products (min - max)
2. the list of all possible options and values (Size, Color and the corresponding values xl, s, xxl, yellow, red, blue)
3. manufacturer (Nike, Addidas, ....)
4. categories

I will then use these info to build a filter which users can use to narrow down the result list (similar to filters seen on many other ecommerce sites such as Amazon, Overstock, Ebay,...)

I looked into facet search but not sure if that's what I want, I would love to find a way to retrieve all the information I need with the smallest amount of queries possible.

Answer (score 1):

[Facets](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-facets.html) are definitely the way to go when it comes to the style of Amazon category search. For retrieving all the facets in the smallest amount of queries as possible you can very easily do this, just include more. I used Sense chrome extension because it's really pretty and easy to use for search examples. For this example I'm placing a few product documents with name, price, manufacturer, category, color. As you can see we've searched on all these facets in a match all. You can do the query you like and even do global facets, or any number of facets( range, histograms ect..). It really all depends on what documents you want, and how the data is formed. A very exciting portion of this is the next big thing [Aggregations](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/master/search-aggregations.html)! You can do awesome searches with aggregations. Say you have a timestamp and a location, you could have a aggregation on a color between a time in a specific location. qbox.io will have a blog post about some interesting things you can do with aggs in the coming days.

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index

PUT /test_index/product/1
{
   "name":"prod1",
   "price":19.95,
   "manufacturer":"manu1",
   "category":["cat1","cat2"],
   "color":"red"
}

PUT /test_index/product/2
{
   "name":"prod2",
   "price":25,
   "manufacturer":"manu2",
   "category":["cat2","cat3"],
   "color":"yellow"
}

PUT /test_index/product/3
{
   "name":"prod3",
   "price":4.99,
   "manufacturer":"manu2",
   "category":["cat1","cat2","cat3"],
   "color":"yellow"
}

PUT /test_index/product/4
{
   "name":"prod4",
   "price":19.95,
   "manufacturer":"manu3",
   "category":["cat1","cat3"],
   "color":"blue"
}

POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
       "match_all": {}
   },
   "facets" : {
       "price_stats" : {
           "statistical" : {
               "field" : "price"
           }
       },
       "color_terms" : {
           "terms": {
              "field": "color",
              "size": 10
           }
       },
       "manufacturer_terms" : {
           "terms": {
              "field": "manufacturer",
              "size": 10
           }
       },
       "category_terms" : {
           "terms": {
              "field": "category",
              "size": 10
           }
       }
   }
}`
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting to get ahead of the ElasticSearch game, why not check out the latest beta of ElasticSearch, found [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/downloads/1-0-0-beta2/) which includes **aggregations**. [Here](https://www.found.no/foundation/elasticsearch-aggregations/) is a nice blog article explaining aggregations and the differences it has with facets, and its endless possibilities.

ElasticSearch 1.0.0 can't be far away so don't worry too much about being part of a beta program.